# How to change state value periodically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Carousal() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(image_1);

 
  return (
    <div>
          
            {setInterval(() => {setImage(image_1)}, 1000)}
            {setInterval(() => {setImage(image_2)}, 2500)}
            {setInterval(() => {setImage(image_3)}, 3500)}
            
             {Note : above functions are for state change}

            <img src={image}  />
         
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Problem** : The above timing function change state periodically,but after 4 seconds images changes uncontrollably

**Question:** How can I change the state in every 1 second ? The  repetition of images desired.

image_3/image_2 = Represent image location

Comment: In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel, react-slick does this.

Comment: Thanks,I will look into this,

Comment: At time 1,2,3,4,5,6,... image1 will appear. At time 2.5, 5,... image2 will appear. At time 3.5, 6. (Time in seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep an index to the current image in `state`, then define a method to increment it every second. Call that method in `useEffect` to kick things off at page load, and then populate the `img` with the correct image by indexing the array.

```js
function Carousel() {
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const images = ["image_1", "image_2", "image_3"];

  const nextImage = () => {
    setImageIndex(prev => (prev + 1) % images.length)
    setTimeout(nextImage, 1000)
  }

  React.useEffect(nextImage, [])
  return (
    <div>
       <img src={images[imageIndex]} alt={images[imageIndex]}/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <Carousel /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated the brilliance